# Is there anything like Haskell's 'maybe' function built into Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What I'm looking for is this function:

```
def maybe[A, B](a: Option[A])(f: A => B)(g: () => B): B = a match 
{
    case Some(x) => f(x)
    case None => g()
}
```

It's in the Haskell prelude so I'm thinking it might be in the Scala standard library somewhere and I've just missed it. I hate having to recode it in projects so I'm wondering if anyone knows where it is, or if it's definitively not there. Or is there a better method for getting this functionality?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do

```
val opt:Option[A] = // ...
val result:B = opt.map(f).getOrElse(g());
```

`getOrElse` takes a by-name parameter, so `g` will only be evaluated if `opt` is `None`.

Comment: Why `a => f(a)` instead of just `f`?

Answer (score 16):

Other answers have given the `map` + `getOrElse` composition.  Just for the record, you can "add" a `maybe` function to `Option` in the following way:

```
implicit def optionWithMaybe[A](opt: Option[A]) = new {
  def maybe[B](f: A=>B)(g: =>B) = opt map f getOrElse g
}
```

It's worth noting that the syntax of higher-order functions in Scala is usually nicer when the function parameter comes last.  Thus, a better way to organize `maybe` would be as follows:

```
def maybe[B](g: =>B)(f: A=>B) = opt map f getOrElse g
```

This could be used as follows:

```
val opt: Option[String] = ...
opt.maybe("") { _.toUpperCase }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use scalaz, and then you have an implicit conversion to `OptionW` which has `fold`, or you can use Scala 2.10.0-M3 and use the builtin `Option.fold`

```
scala> Some(1).fold(5)(_ * 2)
res5: Int = 2

scala> (None: Option[Int]).fold(5)(_ * 2)
res7: Int = 5
```

Note that the scalaz fold signature is `fold[X](some: A => X, none: => X)`, while the builtin seems to be `fold[X](none: => X)(some: A => X)`.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the function is already in the standard library in the latest version

Answer (score 4):

The method would be called fold if it were to adhere to convention (see Either.fold which is the catamorphism for Either).

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`Option.fold`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option@fold[B](ifEmpty:=>B)(f:A=>B):B) for this:

```
opt.fold(g)(f)
```

Note that `g` is by-name, just like `getOrElse`. Also note the inversion of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.  The best I could come up with is to chain Option's "map" and "getOrElse" together:

```
scala> var a: Option[String] = Some("hello")
a: Option[String] = Some(hello)

scala> a.map(_.toUpperCase).getOrElse("empty") 
res19: java.lang.String = HELLO

scala> a = None
a: Option[String] = None

scala> a.map(_.toUpperCase).getOrElse("empty")
res21: java.lang.String = empty
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. However, I'd write it to take `g` by name:

```
def maybe[A, B](a: Option[A])(f: A => B)(g: => B): B = a.map(f).getOrElse(g)
```

This is more Scala- and Haskell-like and a bit nicer to use.